# (char) (i + 'a') JAVA: what's happening here?

Tags: java

I encountered a similar piece of code:

```
public class print {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            System.out.print((char) (i + 'a'));
        }
    }
}
```

If I run it, I get "abcdef".

My question regards this expression: `(char) (i + 'a')`.

I kind of intuitively get what's going on, but I want a rigorous step-by-step explanation of how the computer translates it. As indicated in some answers, the char is simply a number displayed as a character. Fine, but what does this syntax with parentheses actually do? Is it a conversion? Can I use it for other types as well?

Comment: `char` is a primitive, not an object, so a "`char`-type object" doesn't make sense.

Comment: char is converted to int using asci value of character. I feel like this question has been answered before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ASCII value](http://www.asciitable.com/) of `a` is `97`.

```
When i = 0, i + 'a' = 0 + 97 => When cast into char, it will be a
When i = 1, i + 'a' = 1 + 97 => When cast into char, it will be b
When i = 2, i + 'a' = 2 + 97 => When cast into char, it will be c
...and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Java `char` is a 16-bit integral type. `'a'` is the same as `97`, which you can see with `System.out.println((int) 'a');` - it follows that `98` is `'b'` and so on across the entire ASCII table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `char` as an `integer` value and vise versa

Below code may help:

```
char aChar = 'a'; // a char
int aCharAscii = aChar; // 97

char bChar = 'a' + 1; // b char
int bCharAscii = aChar + 1; // 98
```